# Main class not found in .jar file despite the .jar contains the files

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a `.jar` with a main class that I want to access. However, I have not been able to do so.

I first tried modifying the `MANIFEST`, but `java` always complained about

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

So I directly started using the `-classpath` flag like this:

```
java -classpath add2.jar add2.AddClass
```

However, it still gives me the same error.
If I do `jar tvf add2.jar` it will give me the following output:

```
     0 Tue Jun 30 11:49:48 COT 2015 META-INF/
    95 Tue Jun 30 11:49:48 COT 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Dec 05 09:09:22 COT 2014 add2/
169482 Fri Dec 05 09:09:18 COT 2014 add2/add2.ctf
  1786 Fri Dec 05 09:09:22 COT 2014 add2/Add2MCRFactory.class
  3848 Fri Dec 05 09:09:22 COT 2014 add2/AddClass.class
   318 Fri Dec 05 09:09:22 COT 2014 add2/AddClassRemote.class
 12288 Tue Jun 30 11:49:44 COT 2015 META-INF/.MANIFEST.MF.swp
```

So I suspect the `add2.AddClass` is in fact present. I have tried also `AddClass` without the package, with no luck.

### Edit

I modified the `MANIFEST` by unzipping and zipping back together the `.jar`, using the `jar` command.

If I unzip the `.jar`. and execute `javap add2/AddClass.class` I will get:

```
Compiled from "AddClass.java"
public class add2.AddClass extends com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWComponentInstance<add2.AddClass> {
    public add2.AddClass() throws com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException;
    ...
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    ...
    static {};
}
```

Comment: How, exactly, did you modify the manifest?  What does the `main` method of AddClass look like?  What is the `package` statement for AddClass?

Comment: I do not have the source code of where the `.jar` came from, so I cannot answer the last two questions. I will update the question with what I can tell.

Comment: Note: I also tried using `java -cp add2.jar add2.AddClass` on an unmodified `.jar`, with no luck.

Comment: Do I understand correctly (you did not delete it), that the `AddClass` has no `main` method? In that case, the jar cannot be run directly.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake copying the output. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is, that your `AddClass` inherits from `com.mathworks...` class.. But you did not add this class to the classpath. To generate a packed jar file, you need to use a special classloader like onejar (http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/). Otherwise just add the missing jars to the `-cp` classpath list.

This sample here will not throw a `ClassNotFound` Exception but a `Main class cannot be found or loaded` error.

- compile class Test and Test2
- remove Test2 from the classpath
- run `java -cp . Test`

The Mainclass will not be loaded.

```
import bla.Test2;

public class Test extends Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "TEST1";

        System.out.println(test);

    }
}
```

Where `Test2.java` is

```
package bla;

public class Test2 {
    public Test2() {
        String test = "TEST2";

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: You were right. Thank you very much. It's working now. I just had to add the MATLAB `.jar` and it worked. It is surprising the error that it throws, I think it's misguiding.

Comment: Yes, it could be clearer. I was suspicious but had to ensure with the class sample.